# view content of directory made with ant xml

Tags: xml, ant, maven-ant-tasks

I have an xml file with ant tasks.

One of the tasks is

```
<mkdir dir="someDirectory"/>
```

How can I view the contents of this directory?

I tried

```
<echo>ls someDirectory</echo>
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

How you do it likely depends on what you need to do with the resulting information.

Here's some ideas that might help.

```
<property name="dir" value="someDirectory" />

<fileset dir="${dir}" id="myls" />
<echo>${toString:myls}</echo>

<exec executable="sh">
  <arg line=" -c 'ls -alF ${dir}'" />
</exec>
```

The first uses a `<fileset>` to gather the set of files, then the `toString` helper to show the list.

The second runs the unix `ls` command using an [`<exec>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task - which is what you appear to be trying.

For a test directory I get this output:

```
 [echo] 1:2:3:4

 [exec] total 0
 [exec] drwxr-xr-x  6 mjc  staff  192 10 Apr 11:30 ./
 [exec] drwxr-xr-x  6 mjc  staff  192 10 Apr 11:32 ../
 [exec] -rw-r--r--  1 mjc  staff    0 10 Apr 11:28 1
 [exec] -rw-r--r--  1 mjc  staff    0 10 Apr 11:28 2
 [exec] -rw-r--r--  1 mjc  staff    0 10 Apr 11:28 3
 [exec] -rw-r--r--  1 mjc  staff    0 10 Apr 11:30 4
```